# What is the proper syntax for an ansible inventory file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, ansible

This is my `inventory.yml` file:

```
[hosts]
somedns1.aws.com
somedns2.aws.com
somedns3.aws.com
somedns4.aws.com
somedns5.aws.com
```

But I'm getting `--list ([Errno 8] Exec format error)`

It looks fine as per [this link](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/intro_inventory.html), any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inventory file is probably executable.
Also, inventory files are not in YAML format (hence extension for your inventory is misleading).

Try :

```
mv inventory.yml inventory
chmod a-x inventory
```

and it should be better.